# Content Organizer Rule on Document Set

Tags: content-organizer, document-set

Can i create a content organizer rule on the [Document Set] content type? 
I don't seem to figure it out. If yes, how?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep you can.

You need to make sure that you have the Document Set feature enabled on the Site Collection and then from the Content Organizer Rules you can specify the Group as 'Document Set Content Types' and the type as 'Document Set'.

One thing people frequently forget is that you also need to have the content type available within the destination library that the content will be routed to, so make sure that you have bound the Document Set content type to the library.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Not so fast :P
You need to have also enabled "Content Organizer" feature in site scoped features to do rule sets.

SAV